# Python get second item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a basic website and using MySQL to get stored password data.

Code to get a password from the database:

```
def getPassword(userID, db):
    SQL = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE user_id = %s"
    args = userID
    result, data = db.selectionQuery(SQL, args)
    print(type(data))
    if result:
        return data
    else:
        print("Error in query: ", data)
        return False
```

`db.selectionQuery` function (most likely not relevant):

```
def selectionQuery(self, sql, args=False):
    # Takes the SQL and any arguments. Arguments must be in the form of a tuple
    # Returns a bool value for the success of the query and the data or the error statement
    cursor = self.connectDB()
    if cursor is not False:
        if args is False:
            # No arguments
            try:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                # Close the cursor
                cursor.close()
                self.db.close()
                return True, data
            except (pymysql.Error, pymysql.Warning) as e:
                print(e)
                return False, "Error in query." + str(e)
        else:
            # Arguments
            try:
                cursor.execute(sql, args)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                # Close the cursor
                cursor.close()
                self.db.close()
                return True, data
            except (pymysql.Error, pymysql.Warning) as e:
                print(e)
                return False, "Error in query." + str(e)
    else:
        return False, "Error connecting to DB."
```

`data` variable is a `<class 'list'>` which contains `[{'password': '71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424'}]`

With the password, I run it through my validate_password function:

```
def validate_password(key, password):
    split_key = wrap(key, 64)
    key_salt = bytes.fromhex(split_key[0])
    key_hash = bytes.fromhex(split_key[1])
    print("key salt is: " + str(key_salt))
    print("key hash is: " + str(key_hash))

    temp_key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode('utf-8'), key_salt, 135782)

    if secrets.compare_digest(key_hash, temp_key):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

to get the error:

```
  File "C:\x\app\lib\password.py", line 28, in validate_password
    split_key = wrap(key, 64)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\textwrap.py", line 379, in wrap
    return w.wrap(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\textwrap.py", line 351, in wrap
    chunks = self._split_chunks(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\textwrap.py", line 337, in _split_chunks
    text = self._munge_whitespace(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\textwrap.py", line 154, in _munge_whitespace
    text = text.expandtabs(self.tabsize)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

The problem is that the wrap is expecting just the password `71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424` instead of what is being returned (from the database): `[{'password': '71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424'}]`

Now how do I get the actual password out of this list `[{'password': '71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424'}]` and into a string? I have tried converting it to an array, string and dict to no avail.

To reiterate what I want:
How do I turn the list `[{'password': '71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424'}]`
into a string: `71cf12724462a57af2effd96223f13e3cc2d11eb0259bada9abf6a5a5a50c85892cbad9b8e00a01f1b1f4c2cebfb665c34691eb320e3a61b6e22081373cbd424`?

Comment: You have a dictionary in a list. So first get a dictionary from the list. List indexes are zero-based. And then the value for key "password" from the dictionary.

Comment: `data[0]['password']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to "How do I turn the list into a string": It is returning a dictionary inside of a list, so call the first index of the list to return just the dictionary, then use 'password' as the key for the dictionary to return the password.

```
if result:
    return data[0]['password']
```